# Disable specified checkbox inside the UltraListView based on index

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am having a `UltraListView` and some items with checkbox in it. Now I have to disable the specified checkbox with help of `index` give.

For eg: If i provide '0' then i should get the first checkbox disabled and if I provide '1' the second checkbox should get disabled.

//Code

```
Me.lvUnlink.Items(O).Control.ViewSettingsList.CheckBoxStyle = UltraWinListView.CheckBoxStyle.CheckBox
```

I tried like the above code and it disables all the checkboxes. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to solve this task. Maybe one of the easiest solutions could be if you are using instance of UltraListViewItemCheckBoxUIElement. For example:

```
UltraListViewItemCheckBoxUIElement elem = e.Element.GetDescendant(typeof(UltraListViewItemCheckBoxUIElement),ultraListView1.Items[3]) as UltraListViewItemCheckBoxUIElement;
        if (elem != null) elem.Enabled = false;
```

If you want to disable/enable specific item/items using an index, you should specify the context in your GetDescendant() method

If you have any questions, feel free to write me